# Responsive Design for my Razor views inside asp.net mvc web application

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, media-queries

0I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and I am using a responsive web template which is based on bootstrap. Currently the layout is responsive, where the page will adapt to the screen size to a certain limit, for example if I have a table with only four columns and the user access it using a small screen then the text can still be readable. but for some views there have tables with more than 8 columns , the text inside these tables became un-readable when beginning accessed from small size screens. As follow:-

[image]

On way I am thinking to fix this issue, is to manually define `hidden-xs hidden-sm` classes for the columns that are less important to the users and only display the columns that are most important , when the user access the system from small or extra small screens.
I am afraid that by approach might work, but it is very handy? Can anyone advice on this please?

Thanks
my view code looks as follow:-

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
<thead>
<tr>



        <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.SingleOrDefault().UserName)
        </th>
        <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.SingleOrDefault().AuditAction.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.SingleOrDefault().TechnologyType.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.SingleOrDefault().Technology.Tag)
        </th>
        <th>
              @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.SingleOrDefault().DateTimeStart)
        </th>
        <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.SingleOrDefault().DateTimeEnd)
        </th>
                                  <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.SingleOrDefault().ExtraInfo)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
    <tbody>


        @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <td>
    <span class="yellow b">     @item.UserName</span>
        </td>
        <td>
    @(item.AuditAction == null ? "None" : item.AuditAction.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
    @(item.TechnologyType == null ? "None" : item.TechnologyType.Name)
        </td>

//code goes here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before your `<table>` wrap it with the bootstrap class `<div class="table-responsive">`. This class will make it scroll-able horizontally, what I did was to then add a comment to the user to inform them that they can "swipe" the table left and right (just on mobile). This together with hiding what you don't want to show as you mentioned is the only decent option for tables.

Hope that helps

Comment: so for now i manually add class="hidden-phone" on the columns that are less important to the users , which will hide the columns only on mobile phone browsers. i tested the result on some phone simulators and the view became less crowded and 100% readable. so i think it is fear enough ,, although this method is quite handy , but works well.. can u advice ?

Comment: This is your best bet for now, keep in mind that the "items" you hide with .hidden-phone will still load in the DOM - that's if you're bothered about browser performance.